# How do I apply conditional logic when merging two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes:

df1:

```
region    id    name
us        2      twiggs
us        3      twiggs
ca        5      starbucks
```

and
df2:

```
account   employees
     us        5
```

I'd like to do a join between df2 and df1. If i do a simple join I get

```
account   employees     id    name
us          5          2      twiggs
us          5          3      twiggs
```

however I'd like to add some custom logic so that I can use another lookup function that calculates the id and picks between 2 and 3 and results in

```
account   employees     id    name
us          5          2      twiggs
```

or

```
account   employees     id    name
    us          5          3      twiggs
```

based on the lookup function `findId(row)` which looks at number of employees to determine the correct Id.

Comment: The join operation in pandas is flexible as the one in SQL. You can apply `findId` on every in `df2` then join based on the new column

Comment: could you show example of  `custom logic `?